# How to get m_PathID of an Object from a release Unity game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reverse-engineering, assets

I found that there's no easy way to use BepInEx to see `m_PathID` of a game object loaded from an asset package in a running release Unity game.

So the question is: is there some way to do it or is it only present in asset files and used for `instanceID` generation? What UnityPlayer function can I tap into to get it?

Although there seem to be

```
InstanceIDToLocalSerializedObjectIdentifier(int, LocalSerializedObjectIdentifier &)
```

internal function that fills

```
struct LocalSerializedObjectIdentifier {
    int localSerializedFileIndex;
    long localIdentifierInFile;
}
```

kind of structure that seems to contain it(?) but it's not working for me.

(I know mostly C# but any other language example will be fine too.)